# The Correct Meaning of Genesis 6:3 - Also Flesh or Is Flesh?

Tags: genesis, spirit, translation-philosophy

This is a translational issue and, depending on how Genesis 6:3 is rendered, its meaning changes greatly. For a Christian reader this matter of spirit or flesh (or both) is highly relevant.

Here is the same verse in three translations:

**American King James Version**

> And the LORD said, "My spirit shall not always strive with man, for
>   that he **also** is flesh: yet his days shall be an hundred and twenty
>   years" (my emphasis).

**English Standard Version**

> Then the LORD said, “My Spirit shall not abide in man forever, for he
>   **is flesh**: his days shall be 120 years" (my emphasis).

**NET Bible**

> So the LORD said, "My spirit will not remain in humankind
>   indefinitely, **since they are mortal**. They will remain for 120 more
>   years" (my emphasis).

The first translation (viz., *also*) implies "he is also comprised of flesh" or that he is not *only* spirit. The second translation gives attention to the flesh alone, whereas the third emphasizes the mortality of the flesh. Other translations I've not included translate *flesh* as "he is corrupt" or something similar.

According to the translation, then, or even the context of the verse, what is being implied here? That man is *also* flesh, or that he *is flesh*, or that he *is mortal*, or that he *is corrupt*?

The following link shows the many different renderings which change the meaning of the verse: http://biblehub.com/genesis/6-3.htm